# AFNetworking 2.0 : isReachable always returns False

Tags: objective-c, ios7, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking 2.0 for Reachability check in my application. However, reachable property is always returning false. Please see the code

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];

 _isInternetReachable = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable ;

 [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"Reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));

        if (status)
            _isInternetReachable = YES;
        else
            _isInternetReachable = NO;

  }];
```

When I check _isInternetReachable after my second line, it always returns false. But once my app is launched, it goes in the status change block and sets _isInternetReachable to Yes. 
I am not able to figure out this behavior. I am testing this on a Simulator. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try using following code.

**Monitoring code**

```
self.manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

self.manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

__block ViewController *blocksafeSelf = self;

    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = self.manager.operationQueue;

    [self.manager.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {

//        NSLog(@"stats: %d", self.manager.reachabilityManager.isReachable);
        [blocksafeSelf finish];

        switch (status) {
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
                // we need to notify a delegete when internet conexion is lost.
                // [delegate internetConexionLost];
                NSLog(@"No Internet Conexion");
                break;
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
                NSLog(@"WIFI");
                break;
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
                NSLog(@"3G");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"Unkown network status");
                [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];
                break;
        }
    }];// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.manager.reachabilityManager startMonitoring];
```

**Callback method:**

```
-(void)finish

{

NSLog(@"---:%d", self.manager.reachabilityManager.isReachable);

}
```